# fabricjs, different size and coords of clip area in non windows OS

Tags: javascript, linux, fabricjs

I set canvas size 800х800. Clip area size is `{'width':223, 'height':196}`
and coords `{'left':144, 'top':97}`. I use windows OS
But somehow the clip area is different on other OS'es, non windows.

Here's an example: `https://jsfiddle.net/ansaus/8gv95y57/5/`
I expect it to look like this http://take.ms/M2J1X but it 
actually looks like http://take.ms/qaoU0 on non Windows systems

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks right on my screen with OSX. I wonder if the problem is not OS but based on the pixel ratio? Often times retina screens have unexpected behavior with canvas. try this: `https://gist.github.com/paulkaplan/6050309`

Comment: thank you! it saved my time. though the only workaround for me was to set fabric pixel ratio to 1 like this `fabric.devicePixelRatio = 1;`